# Minimize the info in a signature segment using RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, .net, xml, cryptography

I have a XML file that looks like this

```
<Licence>
      <Name>Test company</Name>
      <Version>1.1.1.1</Version>
      <NumberOfServer>2</NumberOfServer>
</Licence>
```

I then use a previous generated private key to sign the XML file using the foloowing code

```
private void SignFile(XmlDocument doc)
{
    SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc2);

    _cryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(XmlDocument.Load("private.key").Root.ToString());

    signedXml.SigningKey = _cryptoServiceProvider;

    Signature XMLSignature = signedXml.Signature;

    Reference reference = new Reference("");

    XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
    reference.AddTransform(env);

    XMLSignature.SignedInfo.AddReference(reference);

    signedXml.ComputeSignature();

    XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

    doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc2.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

    doc.Save("signed.xml");
}
```

I  get a file looking like this and that validates with the public key!

```
<Licence>
  <Name>Test company</Name>
  <Version>1.1.1.1</Version>
  <NumberOfServer>2</NumberOfServer>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <DigestValue>tmGyr97mgGDviRpzcWjpMdNNMSI=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>Vc5R/OWiup4Rv7+1Tu8Ino83P0mh6npLkNYEaq0QVa6j+OvISOPERO57EllCQWdB1Lgjc7B+lmV4JiSvdfovkldhNZb4+iFgdrI+qOdSEIsBk/KhGS93PfekhDd3qirGerpeGbLAEqZ36jT0aT/QruZXpOX6Y6H5fqGj4prUZaM=</SignatureValue>
  </Signature>
</Licence>
```

***BUT*** do I have to have the SignedInfo field in there and how can I get rid of it?

I use something like this to validate.

```
    _cryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(XDocument.Load("public.key").Root.ToString());

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("signed.xml");

    SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);

    XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");
    signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

    bool valid = signedXml.CheckSignature(_cryptoServiceProvider);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't remove the `SignedInfo` element. There are a couple of reasons:

1. It is required by the XML Signature Schema. If you remove it, software that supports XML Signature will break.
2. The `SignatureValue` is computed over `SignedInfo`. If `SignedInfo` is absent, there is nothing to verify.

In a license file, where the message verifier might know the digest algorithm and other parameters though some "out-of-band" means, I suppose you could argue that the verifier could reconstruct the `SignerInfo` structure. But, it seems hard to justify breaking the standard and doing the extra work required.

Comment: OK. I kind thought so to but somehow convinced myself into believing it was easier that it was. Thanks. Nice answer.